# Get Largest City Population

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure if the percentage even works, I've tried looking at similar problems. But if it does work all I need then is the `LargestCity` column to show.

Output should be something like this:

```
Country Name - United States
LargestCity  - New York
CityPopulation - 8008278                   
Percentage to the country population - 2.88
```

What I have :

```
SELECT 
    co.Name, co.Population, 
    MAX(ci.Population), 
    ((MAX(ci.Population) * 100) / Co.Population) “PercentageOfCountryPopulation”
FROM 
    Country co
JOIN 
    City ci ON (co.Code = ci.CountryCode)
WHERE 
    Continent = ‘North America’ OR Continent = ‘South America’
GROUP BY 
    Co.Name
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What does your current output look like? What exactly is the problem your having?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the way you are calculating percentage is wrong.

**Example :**

To calculate percentage of one number to another, a ratio (Y/X = P%):

Formula :

> Y/X = ((Y/X) * 100)% = P%

15 is what percent 150?

```
Step 1: 15/150 = 0.10

step 2:((15/150) * 100) = 10%
```

**Query :**

To find `percentage` of each city population with city with `Maximum population`

```
SELECT co.NAME, 
       co.population, 
       max_population, 
       ( ( co.population / max_population ) * 100 ) as percentageofcountrypopulation
FROM   country co 
       JOIN city ci 
         ON co.code = ci.countrycode 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT countrycode, 
                          Max(population) max_population 
                   FROM   city 
                   GROUP  BY countrycode) mc 
               ON mc.countrycode = co.code 
WHERE  continent = 'north america' 
        OR continent = 'south america'
```

If you want to find the `percentage` of each city population with `total population` in country then replace `Max` aggregate with `Sum` aggregate in

```
(SELECT countrycode, 
        SUM(population) total_population 
 FROM   city 
 GROUP  BY countrycode)
```

Comment: Thanks but how do i add the "Largest City" ?

Comment: What do you mean by **add the "Largest City"**

Comment: The output should have a column "Largest City", thx for the help!